# Can I pass arguments to the entrypoint of a SageMaker estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the [SageMaker python sdk](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Framework) and was hoping to pass in some arguments to be used by my entrypoint, I'm not seeing how to do this.

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn  # sagemaker python sdk

entrypoint = 'entrypoint_script.py'

sklearn = SKLearn(entry_point=entrypoint,  # <-- need to pass args to this
                  train_instance_type=instance_class,
                  role=role,
                  sagemaker_session=sm)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no as there is no parameter on the Estimator base class, or the fit method, that accepts arguments to pass to the entrypoint.

I resolved this by passing the parameter as part of the hyperparameter dictionary. This gets passed to the entrypoint as arguments.

Comment: Just a note: I have around 30 arguments to tune, I was passing the hyperparameters as a YAML formatted string. Although the hyperparameters at SageMaker has a maximum length of 256 (that is not documented). So now I will have to edit my Dockerfile to accept around 30 arguments with suboptions for minimum and maximum for each. Sagemaker is not for the heart fainted or who likes proper documentation.

Comment: 256 character limit is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTrainingJob.html#sagemaker-CreateTrainingJob-request-HyperParameters

Comment: I confirm using a hyperparameter dictionary does the job... is this documented anywhere though?

Answer (score 1):

The entry_point argument here is for a script file that contains the codes you want to run training and prediction.

You can refer to the [example here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/Scikit-learn%20Estimator%20Example%20With%20Batch%20Transform.ipynb)

And the entry_point script above example uses is [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/scikit_learn_iris.py)